is "Side effects of a function are sequenced before its evaluation" specified by the C++ standard?
I didn't find relevant terms in Order of evaluation.
So is the behavior of function g undefined in the code below?
int x;
int f() { return x++; }
void g() { x = f(); }

I compiled the code on different platform and with different args, and it showed that x always stayed unchanged.

No it didn't. It was (a) evaluated in f(); (b) returned by f(); (c) post-incremented in f(); and (d) stored with its original value in g().

In expression x = f() evaluation of f() is sequenced-before evaluation of =. Side effects within f() are not side-effects of this expression. See [intro.execution] section of standard, the relevant rule seems to be paragraph 18 in C++17 final draft ("When calling a function, ...").

@user207421 which term specifically can explain the order between (c) and (d)?

note that unspecified and undefined have subtle but important difference in meaning. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

@463035818_is_not_an_ai If the side effect of f and the assignment in g are unsequenced, it's surely an ub according to the standard.

return x++; this expression has to end before anything else runs.

You have a series of expressions whose value is x followed by an assignment to x. There is no opportunity for the post-increment to x to matter, although it does take place.

Can the close voters explain how is this not reproducible, a typo or "resolved in a way less likely to help future readers"?

@nalemy - Note that x++ returns the old value of x, so it is technically incremented, but then assigned its old value again in g. Thus unchanged. (Of course the compiler might be smart and optimize the code, knowing that the increment is lost and skip it).


is the behavior of function g undefined in the code below?

No.

is "Side effects of a function are sequenced before its evaluation" specified by the C++ standard?

Yes.
I mean, from a logical point of view, a function has to "end" before anything else can start.
Before C++11 and in C, we have "sequence points". Each full expression ends with a sequence point. At the end of full expression return x++ at ; all side effects have to be evaluated.
After C++17 we have this from https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.execution#18 :

For each function invocation F, for every evaluation A that occurs within F and every evaluation B that does not occur within F but is evaluated on the same thread and as part of the same signal handler (if any), either A is sequenced before B or B is sequenced before A

f() has to be value evaluated before assignment to x in x = f(). So all evaluations inside f() have to happen before assignment to x. Including any side effects from return x++;.

That code has defined behaviour.
The rule since C++11 is that the side effect of the assignment is sequenced after the value computations, but not side effects, of both operands. A function call that is not sequenced before or sequenced after another expression is indeterminately sequenced with respect to that evaluation, not unsequenced. It is only undefined if two unsequenced expressions modify the same memory location.
The rule before C++11 is there is a sequence point after the function call.
The value computation and side effects of the expression f() in g come from the execution of the body of f, i.e. x++.

Given that the posted code is well-defined in C and has always been so (due to a sequence point after argument evaluation and another before the function returns, and likely yet a bunch of them in the function body), what exactly in C++ made it undefined prior C++17? Some sources would be nice.

@Lundin I was unsure. Turns out it was defined all along, but for different reasons

Actually cppreference notes it clearly. In the 19th term, it said that: In every simple assignment expression E1 = E2 and every compound assignment expression E1 @= E2, every value computation and side effect of E2 is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of E1.

@nalemy nope, those are the operands of the assignment, not the side effect of the assignment itself. There should really be a "until C++17" box around "(but not the side effects)" in point 8

Further more, is "side effects are sequenced before the function evaluation" specified or denied by the C++ standard?

@nalemy yes, it's in [expr.ass]

The assignment operator aside, sequence points made everything perfectly clear but in C++11 you cannot easily find out how everything is sequenced in relation to each other: argument evaluation, function body including side effects, function return statement, evaluation of the results. This is scattered in a "sequenced before/after" mess all over ISO 14882. Typical C++ WG modus operandi: find something that was previously well-defined and make it undefined. Preferably by hiding, scattering or simply forgetting to include the relevant information.

@Lundin sequence points wouldn't let you specify any memory order except seq_cst

int x;
int f() { return x++; }
void g() { x = f(); }

The behaviour is well defined.
Calling g() would leave x unchanged.
In void g() you assign the value returned by int f() to x.
This is equivalent to writing void g() { int y = f(); x = y; }
The value computation of the expression x++ is sequenced before the side-effect (ie: the increment [++] of x happens after the value of the expression x is computed).
This means that executing f() will return the value of x before it is incremented by 1.
You could write the function like this:
int f() { const int y = x; x = x + 1; return y; }

The observable behaviour is guaranteed to be identical.

x is a global, it is never uninitialised. Globals are zero-initialised.

I've never paid attention to this (because I've never used global variables in C++). You're right! Thank you for pointing it out.
Variables with static or thread storage duration are zero-initialized (in the case of a scalar).
All variables declared at namespace scope have static storage duration. (See: 6.7.5.2 [basic.stc.static]) and the global scope is the namespace scope of the global namespace (See: 6.4.6 [basic.scope.namespace]).
